# python select explorer file

Tags: python, subprocess, explorer

```
import subprocess
path = r"C:/Users/Χρήστος/Desktop/Papinhio player old/notes/cases.txt"
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"'+path+'"')
```

When i run the up code i supposed to open the folder `C:/Users/Χρήστος/Desktop/Papinhio player old/notes/` and highlight-select the file `cases.txt`

The folder and the file exists (for example: `cd C:/Users/Χρήστος/Desktop/Papinhio player old/notes/` works.

I think the above code worked before some months, i don't know now why doesn't work.
I have tried to run the code with two python versions: 3.9.2 and 3.8.9

Can you help me please about?

Instead of this, it opens the My Computer Explorer window.
[image]

I found the problem:

```
import subprocess
import os

path = "C:/Users/Χρήστος/Desktop/Papinhio player old/notes/cases.txt"
path = os.path.abspath(path)
path = path.replace('/', '\\')
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"'+path+'"', shell=True)
```

But if there is a nicer answer i would like to know.

Comment: Just tested, and this seems to happen when the path of the file doesn't exist. Perhaps you've renamed your folders? Otherwise it could be related to some encoding/decoding of special greek characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import subprocess
import os

path = "C:/Users/Χρήστος/Desktop/Papinhio player old/notes/cases.txt"
path = os.path.abspath(path)
path = path.replace('/', '\\')
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"'+path+'"', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it with `shell=True`

```
import subprocess
path = r"C:/Users/Χρήστος/Desktop/Papinhio player old/notes/cases.txt"
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"'+path+'"', shell=True)
```

Comment: No, i found it. if i replace /--> \\ then it works. Is there any function in path module that can i use?

Comment: yes, `import os`, `os.path.join()` is the correct way to parse file paths, you can also use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module

Comment: check the question. I have posted one answer. It is ok?

Comment: Yes it should also work using `abspath`, you won't need the replace though, the os.path module takes care of it